# Private method and normal function in a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, oop, methods

Consider that I have this following module:

```js
class Rectangle {
  private width: number;
  private height: number;

  constructor(w: number, h: number) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
  }

  private area(): number {
    return w * h;
  }

  public show(): void {
    console.log(`${w} X ${h} = ${this.area()}`);
  }
}

export default Rectangle;
```

As you can see the `area` method is set to `private`, so I can move it out of the class and turn it into a normal function. Cause I don't export it, it can't be accessed from outside code.

```js
const area = (w: number, h: number): number => w * h;

class Rectangle {
  private width: number;
  private height: number;

  constructor(w: number, h: number) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
  }

  public show(): void {
    console.log(`${w} X ${h} = ${area(this.width, this.height)}`);
  }
}

export default Rectangle;
```

If I do that, every time I `new` the `Rectangle` class, the `area` won't be created again, so my `Rectangle` object will be more lightweight than the one which has the `private` method. Am I correct? Should I doing this way or stick with the original OOP way?

Comment: The function exists in the object prototype so I don’t think there’s much performance impact but that’s not my area of expertise.  As far as moving the function outside, it makes more sense for it to take the rectangle as an argument rather that separate width and height arguments.  If you go that route you might as well not have a class at all.  Just make Rectangle be an interface with height and width and define functions which act on a Rectangle object.

Comment: An `area` function that takes two numbers is not very useful. You are just doing multiplication, so you may as well abstract to a `multiply = (a, b) => a * b` - it can be reused more effectively, than `area` can. However, if `area` takes a `Rectangle`, that's better, since it can work with your concrete type. Having to call `area(rectangle.height, rectangle.width)` doesn't serve as a good abstraction, you still have to know how to calculate the area in order to call the function that calculates the area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I do that, every time I `new` the `Rectangle` class, the `area` won't be created again, so my `Rectangle` object will be more lightweight than the one which has the `private` method. Am I correct?

No, you are not. A method of a class is stored [in the **prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) of the instances. It is not stored in each instance. There is no impact on performance or memory.

> Should I doing this way or stick with the original OOP way?

I personally prefer to declare independent functions outside the class. It is [a **functional** approach](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0). But it is a matter of coding style.

Notice: if you stick with the OOP paradigm, when a method doesn't use `this` it should be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

This don't change weight of object because it is on object prototype. but if this method is not dependant on class properties then it should / can be static.